# javascript map and filter related issue

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6, filter

I know how filter and map works but was stuck up in a particular scenario

I see that filter returns 0 if no match is found but is there a way to pass on that to map in case there is no match.
eg

```
    const tasks = [
  {
    'name'     : 'Write for Envato Tuts+',
    'duration' : 120
  },
  {
    'name'     : 'Work out',
    'duration' : 60
  },
  {
    'name'     : 'Procrastinate on Duolingo',
    'duration' : 240
  }
];
let difficult_tasks1=tasks.filter(x=>x.duration>=200).map(x=>x? console.log(x):alert("error")); 
console.log(difficult_tasks1.length)
```

above prints as expected i.e first console prints the object x and 2nd prints the length 1

my issue is to get an alert of error when there is no match

```
let difficult_tasks1=tasks.filter(x=>x.duration>=400).map(x=>x? console.log(x):alert("error"));
```

above prints nothing but i was expecting an alert of error.

```
let difficult_tasks1=tasks.filter(x=>x.duration>=400).map(x=>console.log("a"+x));
```

even above doesnt even prints anything..doesnt get to console part in the map

What i want is if nothing is filtered, i still want to return something or show an error

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your filter passes data using `.length` property of array

```
let difficult_tasks1=tasks.filter(x=>x.duration>=200).map(x=>x? console.log(x):alert("error")); 

const filtered = tasks.filter(x => x.duration >= 200)
if (filtered.length > 0) {
   filtered.map((x) => {
      console.log(x)
      return x;
   });
} else {
   alert('Error');
}
```

Comment: thanks..i just simplified the scenario.. In real time, i want my map to run all the times on my filtered array.. 
Basically in my if part I  am doing a callback and if nothing is mapped i want to show an error to the user

Comment: I think you forget map!!

Comment: Don’t need map, what’s the reason

Comment: like i mentioned i am not doing a simple console.log. I want to run a callback
let difficult_tasks1=tasks.filter(x=>x.duration>=200).map(x=>x? callback(x):alert("error")); 

i can obviously do it the way you said. But then i can do whole thing using normal foreach loop etc without filter even...you know what i mean? 

I want to filter a set of array based on a condition and then on the filtered array i want to run a map function...if filter returns something run a specific function (and that bit works btw) but if it returns nothing show an error/alert error